# Re-order form fields on submit url

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a get form with several visible and hidden input fields. When the form is submitted, selected fileds with their values are appended to the url in the order they are placed in the form. Is there a way to re-order the parameters in the url using jQuery? Note that for the reasons of usability, I can not re-order the elements on the form itself.

I know it beggs the question "why would I want to do it?", but the reason is that I will be hitting a static page, so the order of the parameters have to be exactly how they are in the static page url. For example, my form returns a url:

```
http://someurl?names=comm&search=all&type=list
```

while the static page has a url:

```
http://someurl?search=all&type=list&names=comm
```

A simplified form example is here:

```
<form  id="search_form" method="get" action="http://www.cbif.gc.ca/pls/pp/ppack.jump" >

<h2>Choose which names you want to be displayed</h2>
<select name="names">
    <option value="comm">Common names</option>
    <option value="sci">Scientific names</option>
</select>

<h2>Choose how you want to view the results</h2>

<input type="radio" name="search" value="all" id="complete" checked = "checked" />
<label for="complete" id="completeLabel">Complete list</label>
<br/>

<input type="radio" name="p_null" value="house" id="house" />
<label for="house" id="houseLabel">House plants only</label>
<br/>

<input type="radio" name="p_null" value="illust" id="illustrat" />
<label for="illustrat" id="illustratLabel">Plants with Illustrations</label>
<br/>


<input type="hidden" name="type" value="list" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I can get form fields with values using $(#search_form).serializeArray() and massage the array like I want to, but I don't know how to set it back, i.e.  modify the serialized values so that the submitted url has my order of parameters. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go about it, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the double question mark `??` in the url?

Comment: Typo, sorry. Not the actual link, so supposed to be one ?.

Comment: Then edit your question and fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way might be to reorder the actual form elements once the submit button is pressed, while hiding the form so the user doesn't see it.

Another way could be having all visible form elements without a name, and on submit transferring all data to hidden input fields, in the order you prefer.

But in this case, since the data is quite simple (no escaping to be done), you could also compose the URL you want as a string each time some form element changes, and putting it as href of the submit button so you're not really submitting but just following a link.

Comment: Great suggestions. Tried the second one (no names) and it worked with a bit of a workaround. Meaning that name can't be removed from radiobuttons, since it groups them. But removing the element and adding it as a hidden field works.

Third one is brilliant. Don't know why I didn't think of it, but I really don't need a form submit - just need to follow a link.

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion, just out of curiosity, how would I go about implementing it? Removing the elements and adding them back one at a time, or is there a simpler way? 

Thanks!

Comment: Good catch with the name of radio buttons =) Yes, in that case you should remove them and reappend them in the desired order; that's how you move elements in the DOM.